# Issue with Switch Case Statement

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have three methods:

1. The first checks the gender of the user
2. The second checks the housing assortment type
3. The third puts the sorted users into my card adapter

My issue is with the second method `checkHousing()`. If the user chooses Same Sex housing it checks all the other Males who have selected Same Sex housing.Vice-versa for the Female users. So far Iv only been able to get all the the users who have chosen Same Sex, both male and female.

Any suggestions? I feel like there is a more efficient way to do this but cant seem to figure it out.

By the way, I'm using Firebase Real Time database to store the user's info.

```
private String userSex;
private String thisUserSex;
public void checkUserSex() {
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference userDb = usersDb.child(user.getUid());
    userDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("sex").getValue() != null) {
                    userSex = dataSnapshot.child("sex").getValue().toString();
                    switch (userSex) {
                        case "Male":
                            thisUserSex = "Male";
                            break;
                        case "Female":
                            thisUserSex = "Female";
                            break;
                      }
                    checkHousing();
                } } }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        } }); }

private String housingType;
private String assortment;
public void checkHousing() {
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final DatabaseReference userDb = usersDb.child(user.getUid());
    userDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("Housing").getValue() != null) {
                    housingType = dataSnapshot.child("Housing").getValue().toString();
                    switch (housingType) {
                        case "Same Sex":
                            assortment = "Same Sex";
                            break;
                        case "Uni-Sex":
                            assortment = "Uni-Sex";
                            break;
                    }   if (assortment == "Same Sex") dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals(thisUserSex);

                        else { assortment = "UniSex";
                     }
                   }
                 }getRoomMates();
                }
                 @Override
                 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }

       public void getRoomMates(){
         usersDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("Housing").getValue() != null) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && 
                     !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("nope").hasChild(currentUId) && 
                     !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("yeps").hasChild(currentUId) && 
                     dataSnapshot.child("Housing").getValue().toString().equals(assortment)) {
                        String profileImageUrl = "default";
                        if (!dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().equals("default")) {
                            profileImageUrl = 
                      dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().toString();
                        }
                        cards item = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), 
                        dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(), profileImageUrl);
                        rowItems.add(item);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } } }
```

Comment: So basically it is about a user? why you need to check separately?

Comment: So basically you want to use `thisUserSex` in the other query, right? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo My bad it was late when I posted this. Yes, its about the users. For example, if a male users selects Same Sex, I need to collect all the other Male users who have also chosen Same Sex. Vice-versa for Female users.

Comment: You did not answer my question. Do you want to use `thisUserSex` in the other query?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, I do.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the `Same Sex` into `Same SexM` and`Same SexF` and store those seperatley, and then chose the roommates based on the `M` or `F` in the database.
Inside of the switch:

```
if(thisUserSex.equalsIgnoreCase("Male"){
  assortment = "Same SexM";
}else{
  assortment = "Same SexF";
}
```

Comment: Could this be done by setting assortment equal to a datasnapshot of the male or female users instead of storing them separately?

Answer (score 0):

Check what information is in the database, I have had instances where the data is not being changed during run time and that might be the cause of it always returning the same result. I know that you can use a debug mode in most editors or you can print out the current value for the string housing type.

Edit: Looking closer at the code you are using a real time database so check if the information you are submitting is getting processed correctly.